# Powershell search hits within column & return column name

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I'm looking for a way (if possible) to find any hits within any column that contain a ";"  semicolon character and return the column/field name.

I'm basically loading in a DAT delimited text file (or csv). The headers will be different each time, but I'm basically trying to figure out if I will be expecting any of the columns to contain multi-delimited values within the column such as email CC or BCC.

I'm using a form with a text box to input the DAT/CSV.

```
$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $textBox.Text 
    $x
}
```

Here is my code for output file:

```
  Get-Content $x |
    foreach {$_ -replace "þ", '"'} |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "" |
    Out-GridView
```

I have been able to search a hit on the entire CSV by using:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content $x
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern ';' -AllMatches
$Matches.Matches.Count
```

The above part does giving me the total number of ";" hits. But I'd rather see which columns hit, I don't really need a total count, just the header name or column number.

I'm using powershell ISE v5.

Comment: `ipcsv $x | % { $_.PSObject.Properties } | ? Value -match ';' | % Name`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Select-String to to find the initial hits which would be quicker than looping through each column and row. You can the loop through the results by converting each found row into a CSV and then an object. All you need to do then is loop though each property and output the results. Something like this:

```
$file = 'your_file.csv'
$head = Get-Content $file -TotalCount 1
$re = ';'

Select-String $file -Pattern $re | % {
  $line = $_
  $item = $head + "`n" + $_.line | ConvertFrom-Csv
  $item | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name | % {
    if($item."$_" -match $re) {
      New-Object psobject -property @{
        Column = $_
        Row = $line.Linenumber
        Value = $item."$_"
      }
    }
  }
}
```